# Guide Me with good Selenium Tutorial

Tags: selenium

I am new to automation testing tools i like to learn Selenium tool please guide me with right tutorial whether i need to be well versed with any scripting languages or any platform to pass commands..If it is a video tutorial it will be more useful to me and other beginners of Selenium..

Answer (score 6):

Definitely start with the official documentation, as Zugwalt suggested. Beyond that here are a couple suggestions:

One of the first things you will appreciate with Selenium is that you can specify *locators* (expressions to select something on your web page) in several different languages: XPath, CSS, DOM, or Selenium-native variants. And you do not have to choose one up front; you can mix and match them (though there are definite performance differences to be aware of). As you learn you may want to understand how to map from one of these syntaxes to another, which is where [XPath, CSS, DOM and Selenium: The Rosetta Stone and Cookbook](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/) comes in. It is a wallchart that presents a large assortment of recipes across all four syntaxes so it is simple to convert from one to another.

I have also written a getting started guide entitled [Web Testing with Selenium Sushi: A Practical Guide and Toolset](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/web-testing-with-selenium-sushi-a-practical-guide-and-toolset/) that, while written in the context of Selenium 1, still has value that applies to Selenium 2 installations as well.

Comment: If  you find it helpful, it is customary to either upvote it or accept it as an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I always find the [official selenium documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) good, and the *Getting Started With Selenium-WebDriver* section contains example code that should get you on your feet!

Note that since you are just starting with Selenium I would use Selenium 2 WebDriver as Selenium 1 RC is no longer being actively developed.

Answer (score 1):

The publicly-available free Selenium information on the Internet is spotty at best.  There are lots of blog posts, but nothing that presents a coherent discussion or in-depth tutorial.  Both David Burns’ *["Selenium 1.0 Testing Tools: Beginner’s Guide"](https://www.packtpub.com/selenium-1-0-testing-tools-beginners-guide/book)* and Alan  Richardson’s *[“Selenium Simplified - Automated Web Testing with Java and Selenium RC”](http://www.lulu.com/product/paperback/selenium-simplified/14939945)* are great beginner’s books for Selenium and a great deal .  Both are available in paperback and as e-books.

If you want to peek at them, both authors or their publishers offer partial downloads for free ([David](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/0264OS-Chapter-6-First-Steps-with-Selenium-RC.pdf?utm_source=packtpub&utm_medium=free&utm_campaign=pdf), [Alan](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2l9DD6OObL9MGQ3NGU4ODYtZmJlYi00MGY1LWIwNDUtZmM2N2UxODU4OWNm&sort=name&layout=list&num=50)). The e-book prices are very reasonable, and the paperback prices are competitive.

Highly recommended