How to Programmatically Simulate Start and Stop of Chrome DevTools Recorder through the code script in any way possible?
I need to simulate the start and stop of the Chrome DevTools Recorder using code instead of manually doing it.
Any guidance in process would be highly appreciated!
I have seen a lot of documentation stating the steps to open devtools, chosing recorder tab, starting the recording,... But, I am looking for some way to achieve this with specifically  Puppeteer or any other method? Any capability or any sort of api.

The links you have mentioned I have already gone through. This does not currently solve my problem to access the chrome devtools recorder from my own script.

Welcome. Maybe Selenium automates it to an extent?

What do you want to record? Network activity? If so, just slap a page.on("request", ...) and you're good to go.

There is a recorder tab in chrome devtools. You can start or stop recording and that creates a script in json, puppetter, etc. I want to control that recorder tab via my code as @OleksiiKyslytsyn said via selenium, can you please brief on how can I do that?

A DevTools is as another tab in processes. IDK which browser you are on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095446/guide-me-with-good-selenium-tutorial
